# spring mvc created with maven

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I have checked a lot of different links for creating spring mvc with maven but I don't understand why everybody have different xml-files, someone create a webapp login/logout with only pom.xml and web.xml and someone else do the same thing but this one has an applicationservice.xml and an application-dispatcher.xml too. So I'm very confused what roles are and what is the best structure for spring mvc with maven (even JPA and JAX-RS and JAX-B included). How many xml-files I need for a project and so on.

Please
Anyone how have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is about choice, lot of solutions are available. you can have zero spring xml files and [configure it programmatically](http://www.jroller.com/Solomon/entry/programmatic_configuration_in_spring) or put all spring configuration in several xml files (with `<import>`  for instance). For persistence, you can create a simple `META-INF/persistence.xml` with mostly nothing and put all the JPA configuration in your xml spring files, or concentrate all JPA configurations in `META-INF/persistence.xml`.

For my projects my choice is:

- One central XML file for main spring configuration (configuration of beans)
- It contains lots of `<import>` to several other XML files wher I put dedicated configurations:

  - `project-security.xml`
  - `project-persitence.xml` (with a mostly empty `META-INFO/persistence.xml`
  - `project-web.xml`
  - ...